# Does Windows Phone 7 app runs on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, compatibility

Does Windows Phone 7 app run on Windows Phone 8?

Can someone just go to app store with a WP8 and download an app that was built to Windows Phone 7?

Does a simple "hello world" app works in that way without compability issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it works. For example, Windows Phone 8.1 is able to run both Windows Phone 7.X and Windows Phone 8 applications.

Comment: You may also find the relevant MS documentation helpful, as it includes specific information about potential changes between the platforms.  For more, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206947(v=vs.105).aspx.  (Note that you can display the clipped information by resizing the left navigation bar.)